# 'import scipy' hangs in python django after deploying on apache2

Tags: python, django, scipy, apache2

I wrote a python django app that imports `scipy`, as well as many other python modules. It runs perfectly fine when I run django's development server.

Recently I deployed the app on `apache2`. It runs very smoothly and everything looks fine until the app tries to import scipy. Then the site hangs and does nothing. No error message appears in the apache logs. When I run django with `DEBUG=True` I also don't get an error message, but instead the site just hangs.

Scipy was installed with pip in a virtual environment, just like all the other modules (django, wagtail, numpy, and dozens others). Only scipy gives these problems, all the others work fine. I reinstalled scipy, with no effect.
When I run python on the command line (using the same virtual env) and I import scipy, it works. So it looks like it's specific to apache2.

I'm stumped and I'm not sure where to even look or debug anymore, given that only scipy has this issue.

If anyone has a suggestion then I would be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok after digging a bit deeper I found this old post on serverfault:
https://serverfault.com/questions/514242/non-responsive-apache-mod-wsgi-after-installing-scipy

Adding the following line to my /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file did the trick!

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```